# Paypal Subscribe button - Add custom value

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

My question is simple. I want to add a "subscribe" button on my page and apart from the options that "paypal subscribe button" gives to me (i.e. option 1 - value, option 2 - value) I want to capture the e-mail address that the user entered to my system when he/she subscribed or his/her username. How can I capture this information? Is there any way to add my custom field together with these ready-made fields provided by paypal and see that value on my paypal account?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think Paypal allows you to capture that information, nor will they store it.  You will probably need to create a function that stores the value of the email textbox in your own database and report on it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the two variables :

Either use the variable "invoice" and pass the email address as the value in it and it will be displayed in your PayPal account as well as you will receive this variable back in IPN .

Or you can use the variable option 3 variable as a text field and let your buyer enter the email in that and then this variable will be displayed in the PayPal account and in IPN also .

Like this :

```
   <tr><td><input type="hidden" name="on2" value="Text1">Text1</td></tr><tr><td><input type="text" name="os2" maxlength="200"></td></tr>
```

IPN will be like this :
[image]

[image]